# AngularJs - Google map is not visible, it is only visible if I resize browser window

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

Somehow google maps is not showing, it only shows the footer. The map becomes visible when I maximize/minimize or resize the browser window.

Js:

```
$scope.mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.0812981, -96.7357315),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="panel-heading">Google Map</div>
       <div id="map_canvas1" style="min-height:400px" ui-map="myMap"
        ui-event="{'map-zoom_changed': 'setZoomMessage(myMap.getZoom())' }"
        ui-options="mapOptions">
    </div>
```

[Here is an example of how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5G2h.jpg)

Comment: Try removing the event?

Comment: I need the event, anyway I tryed it and doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the solution was to explicitly trigger `resize` event once the map is loaded:

1) register `ui-event="{'map-idle' : 'onMapIdle()'}"`

2) invoke `resize` event:

```
$scope.onMapIdle = function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger($scope.myMap, 'resize');
};
```

**Example**

```js
var app = angular.module('mapApp', ['ui.directives']);

app.controller('mapCtrl', function ($scope) {  
    $scope.mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.0812981, -96.7357315),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    $scope.onMapIdle = function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger($scope.myMap, 'resize');
    };    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
        <div class="panel-heading">Google Map</div>
        <div id="map_canvas1" style="min-height:400px" ui-map="myMap"
             ui-event="{'map-zoom_changed': 'setZoomMessage(myMap.getZoom())', 'map-idle' : 'onMapIdle()' }"
             ui-options="mapOptions">
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this library http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/

Add a map object:

```
$scope.map = {
        center: {
            latitude: 24.0414647,
            longitude: -102.799835
        },
        zoom: 5,
        options: {
            scrollwheel: false
        },
        bounds: {},
        control: {}
    };
```

and then use this function to refresh the map:

```
$scope.renderMap = function () {
        $scope.map.control.refresh({
            latitude: $scope.map.center.latitude,
            longitude: $scope.map.center.longitude
        });
    }
```

Finally, I called renderMap with a button:

```
<button ng-click="renderMap">Update Map</button>
```